# How to define different tooltips for each DataGridCell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Consider the following DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding People}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"  Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age"        Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

My intention was to have the content of each cell also appear as tool tip. [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2031cb7e-3cbf-483b-b9b6-be884de303d7/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-datagrid-cell-in-wpf?forum=wpf)
suggests adding the `Style` to `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` instead of `DataGrid.CellStyle`, but that would result in a lot of redundant code.

The code above causes the following exception: "Cyclic reference found while evaluating the Style property on element 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell: ...'.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly got it right.
The missing piece of the puzzle is what you're binding to from the cell.
It's the text property of the content. The content being a TextBlock.
There may be some complications here with cell edit template of combobox, checkboxes etc.
But you just have datagridtextcolumn there.

```
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Content.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
      </Style>
 </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

In the screenshot below I'm using a sample datagrid I happen to have and examining content using snoop. I've selected the content of a datagridcell in the view so we can see what that's made up of in snoop.

[image]

Not directly related to your question but if you've not examined ui in this way before then notice the parent of any cell is a datagridrow.  Whilst we define datagridtextcolumn in xaml what we get is datagridrows rather than a collection of datagrid columns.